# How to bypass exception and continue the process

Tags: c#, exception, xslt, altova

I am running XSLT 2.0 in C# using altova processor like this:

```
    StreamReader x = new StreamReader(file);
    string y = x.ReadToEnd();
    x.Close();

    string s = TransformByAltovaXML(y, XSLTcontent);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempPath+ "\\" + fileName.Replace(".svg", ".1.svg")))

    {
      writer.Write(s);
      writer.Close();
    }
```

altove processor by default validate transformed XML files,the problem occurs when the file size become more than 5 MB,it throw an exception and doesn't output the file,personally i don't want the validation to occur but it's built in the altova processor instructions,how "in C#" could i continue to StreamWriter step and ignore that exception ?

Comment: If the previous step is breaking, *what would you write*? How is it even meaningful to continue here? The previous step **failed**.

Comment: You should probably do some Try/catches. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Comment: BTW; `File.WriteAllText(tempPath, s);` can replace the last 4 lines, and `string y = File.ReadAllText(file);` can replace the first 3

Comment: @sparkysword already tried them.

Comment: I mentioned it since I didn't see any in your code. Usually my thinking is to put a retry of the action within the catch statement. If it's based on size, why not have the streamreader write until it reaches that size, then create a new file that continues the information. Or just limit it and discard the rest. That way you can  keep the code going and get a portion.